# How to integrate a function of one variable with two instances

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to integrate the following function and have no success.  I know it is not correct because when I check the value on Wolfram alpha it does not match.  It should be around 0.7762

```
amp = 0.413
freq = 4
phi = 20 * np.pi / 180
offset = 0.587
lower_bound = 0
upper_bound = 2 * np.pi

def integrandC(theta, amp, freq, phi, offset):
    return (2/np.pi)*(amp * np.cos(freq*(theta - phi)) + offset) * np.cos(4*theta)

C = integrate.quad(integrandC, lower_bound, upper_bound, args=(amp, freq, phi, offset) )

print C[0] #gives 0.143433
```

I am using Scipy installed through Anaconda for python 2.x.x

I know there is a lot of documentation with reference to integrating a function, but only with the variable mentioned one time in the integral.  I have theta mentioned twice in my example.  The reason I suspect the 
     `np.cos(4*theta)`
is the source of error is because when I do:

```
 def integrandA(theta, amp, freq, phi, offset):
     return (1/np.pi)*(amp * np.cos(freq*(theta - phi)) + offset)
 A = integrate.quad(integrandA, lower_bound, upper_bound, args=(amp, freq, phi, offset) )
```

I get the correct answer of 1.174
Why would the 2nd instance of the variable of integration cause a problem?

Comment: Note I am using `from __future__ import division`

Comment: Double-check that your computation in Wolfram Alpha is exactly the same expression that you are integrating with `quad`.  Are all the constants the same? Are all the parentheses in the right place?

Comment: Are you sure, you implemented the same formulas? Parenthese, frequency vs. angular frequency etc? Why are you subtracting phi only in the first term?

Comment: When I use Wolfram Alpha, it gives 0.143433.

Comment: The calculations were done out by hand and checked with Wolfram alpha.  The formulas are based on a polarimeter experiment shown on http://www.nist.gov/calibrations/upload/ao38-99.pdf

Comment: I suspect that your expression `(amp * np.cos(freq*(theta - phi)) + offset)` is not the same as I(theta) shown in the paper (eqn. A1).  I assume you are trying to compute the value of C shown in eqn. A4.

Comment: This is the exact wolfram line: `integrate (2/pi)*(0.413* cos(4x -(20*pi/180)) + 0.587)*(cos(4x)) from 0 to 2pi` and it gives 0.776 as it should be.

Comment: `cos(4x-(20*pi/180))` is a different expression than `np.cos(freq*(theta - phi))`.  In the Wolfram Alpha calculation, you haven't multiplied `phi` by `freq`.

Comment: I am trying to compute the value of C.  A works as expected.

Comment: My friend you have spotted the error.  Thank you so much.  Correct line should read `((amp * np.cos(freq*theta - phi) + offset) * np.cos(4*theta))`

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer (or remove the question).